# SQL: Not a specific year

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, if I have a table like this

```
----------------------
| id     | year      |
----------------------
| 1      | 01-JAN-95 |
| 2      | 01-JAN-96 |
| 3      | 01-JAN-97 |
| 4      | 02-JAN-97 |
| 5      | 03-JAN-97 |
----------------------
```

...and I wanted to select everything that is not from the year 1997, how would I do this?

I know I can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year not like '%97';
```

But is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(year) <> '1997'`

// fixed logic

Answer (score 3):

If your table is large you might want to try this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE datecol < '1997-01-01'
OR datecol >= '1998-01-01';
```

Comment: +1 This is what you want to do because it avoids having to wrap the `datecol` in a function which would make it non-sargable. By making the comparison using the bare column, MySQL is able to make use of an index range scan operation, which is much more efficient.